# Running "open -a Terminal.app MyScript", opens new terminal window, but doesn't run MyScript in it

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, sublimetext3

I'm on mac, and need to open a new terminal window and run a script/compiled code in it.

Before "`open -a Terminal.app Myscript`" would work, but now it suddenly no longer runs the script.. only opens the Terminal Window.
If i just run the script, it works. Other scripts that worked before no longer work using `open -a` either.

I'm running  Mojave `10.14.3 Beta`. And bash `5.0.0`, linked through Homebrew.
If anyone else can reproduce this, please do. I'm not sure if its a bug, or just a issue with me.

console reveals following error:
/usr/bin/open subsystem: com.apple.launchservices 
"`Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)`" 
This error is triggered everytime the command is run.

I've also searched and haven't found anyone else experiencing this problem, nor alternatives to open -a.

Comment: are you getting any error / exception ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari I'm not. It just opens a fresh terminal window.

Comment: @ManojChoudhari I just checked in console and I do get an error when running the command:
for : /usr/bin/open       subsystem: com.apple.launchservices
"Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)"

Answer (score 0):

It works again now. Not sure if it was due to a restart, or because of another program.